# Postman Sushi Selector demo - test failing based on keyword?

Tags: postman, google-geocoding-api, postman-collection-runner

In finally swimming into the waters of APIs, I've discovered Postman, and holy crap is it an awesome game-changer! They have a cool demo project called [Sushi Selector](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/1559645/RW1VshpT), where you chain together several API calls, then run them as a collection to create an app that merges functionality from the Google Geocoding and Place Search APIs, then harnesses Twitter to send out the results.

They also have a demo up in a [series of videos on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shYn3Ys3ygE&index=5&list=PLM-7VG-sgbtBsenu0CM-UF3NZj3hQFs7E), which are excellent in their depth and flow. Very intuitive and easy to follow along, AND to try to branch out on your own. Instead of building a Sushi Selector for San Francisco, I've been building the Barbecue Finder for New Haven. However, the test code given for the Place Search fails out. The code as presented in the youtube series:

```
let response = pm.response.json();
let choices = [];

for (let i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {

    let establishment = response.results[i];

    if (establishment.opening_hours.open_now && establishment.rating >= 4){
        choices.push({
            "name": establishment.name,
            "rating": establishment.rating,
            "vicinity": establishment.vicinity,
         });
    }
}
pm.environment.set("choices", JSON.stringify(choices));
```

Running the GET API call would bring back a response of about 10-12 barbecue joints, including several that were both open right now ('opening_hours.open_now' = TRUE) and had a rating 4 or more, including this first result.

```
{
    "html_attributions": [],
    "results": [                  <--------------------
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 41.2716997,
                    "lng": -72.9742454
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 41.27280407989272,
                        "lng": -72.97257402010727
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 41.27010442010728,
                        "lng": -72.97527367989272
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
            "id": "6506ce2dbea6328207adb53545109e024e774e1b",
            "name": "Uncle Willie's Smokehouse BBQ",
            "opening_hours": {                <--------------------------
                "open_now": true               <--------------------------
            },
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 750,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109755391798790714147/photos\">A Google User</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAuG2Sb8o07byUTTa0ifo5Ubuq-KELAfvylsoyYNQi41tr6MVyNGsukvFsofpOuBtYvLQnJJf9vR69ow82dFsuaZwrbLecx1xzqy_ds-1FT1D-Gi0rK2IyyGh_CONyl70DEhCdXE5lhHeDN1AwSBwuNx_6GhQ9iUhCG45T85ZOsc_-HPIwOuIS-Q",
                    "width": 1200
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJp3q4ux926IkRGembozhnAj0",
            "plus_code": {
                "compound_code": "72CG+M8 West Haven, Connecticut",
                "global_code": "87H972CG+M8"
            },
            "price_level": 2,
            "rating": 4.1,                     <--------------------------
            "reference": "CmRbAAAA62c_yAa_Safw9JWbRYKjcSXdY5D-xV1XfOrT4H21ouB6OoK6d3oiqkemwqH4IYxboQmmAn1wWDGo7GnhluH2ZjQdHslYDlDrIDhXXeYiHwYMW5uEy4DFLSdLIDU7BarUEhC0bTplHAz_OIR_inV2tmqCGhRDByzFCtlu7VOOKzC4atlM4kaU6Q",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "restaurant",
                "food",
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "473 Saw Mill Rd, West Haven"
        },
```

Every time I ran this against the response from the Google NearbySearch API, it would throw an error, "There was an error evaluating the test script: **Reference Error: open_now is not defined.**"

I searched high and low, and tried to figure out different ways to try to get at the 'open_now' key, to no avail. I found the test code for the publicly available version of the Sushi Selector code, and after putting in my API keys and tweaking the search to be BBQ in New Haven, it ALSO failed with the same error message!

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

let choices = [];

try {

    let response = pm.response.json();

    // loop through all the results 
    for (let i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {

        let establishment = response.results[i];

        // check if each establishment is open now and rated well (you can set your own search criteria here)
        // add the establishments that pass your criteria to the choices array
        if (establishment.opening_hours.open_now && establishment.rating >= 4.0) {
            choices.push({
                "name": establishment.name,
                "rating": establishment.rating,
                "vicinity": establishment.vicinity
            });
        }
    }
}
catch (error) {
    throw error;
}

// set your choices as an environment variable
// remember to wrap JSON.stringify() choices since it's an array
pm.environment.set("choices", JSON.stringify(choices));
```

In frustration, I reset the keyword parameter in the demo Sushi Selector to the original 'sushi' and the test passed! The environment variable choices successfully filled. 
I then tried using 'sushi' in my version, and it ALSO worked! I again tried replacing 'sushi' with 'barbecue' or 'bbq' and the test would fail, but it worked just fine with 'chinese', 'japanese', and 'brazilian.'

**For all that, WHY would these Postman tests fail just because of a different keyword parameter?! Why would it ONLY fail for 'bbq' or 'barbecue'**

Any help is greatly appreciated. My head hurts.

Note: I also tried removing the 'establishment.opening_hours.open_now' criteria from the if statement in my version, leaving just the rating comparison, and the test passed, and the 'choices' array was populated. I added the 'establishment.opening_hours.open_now' status to the 'choices' array ("hours" = establishment.opening_hours.open_now) and THAT worked just fine, populating TRUE and FALSE as appropriate. JUST using it in the If statement, with the keywords 'bbq' or 'barbecue' would fail.

Comment: I tried the same and you can see the results here: https://pasteboard.co/HuUBVp3.png
Not sure why you're getting this error since changing the keyword won't fail javascript or anything inside Postman. Can you share your collection (remove any API keys and other things)?

Comment: To learn how to share a collection visit this link: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collections/sharing_collections
Just reset the environment variables etc. and share the collection and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Seems like a dumb n00b question, which i guess it is, because I clearly am: won't clearing all the keys break what I *do* have working? Or do I make a copy and reset the variables? Thanks!

Comment: It's cool. I think J.Lin has answered it well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Places API is returning at least one search results that does not include the `opening_hours` property.

Instead of filtering your search results by this criteria after you receive the response, you could add the optional `opennow` parameter in your initial request to the Google Places API. According to [the Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#nearby-search-and-text-search-responses):

> `opennow` — Returns only those places that are open for business at the
>   time the query is sent. Places that do not specify opening hours in
>   the Google Places database will not be returned if you include this parameter in your query.

**The way I debugged it in the [Postman console](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/debugging_and_logs#network-calls-with-postman-console):** 
I tried the request with a few different keywords and some threw an error, and some did not. When I added `console.log(establishment.opening_hours);` inside the for loop, I could see which search result (if any) logged a `null` value for `establishment.opening_hours`. Upon inspecting that specific search result in the JSON response, I could see that it didn't have the `opening_hours` property.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for both the clear, concise reason why, AND the tools for how to handle stuff like this in the future. Super-helpful!